# What is the best way to implement a method with 2 returns?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quite often I come across some code where I have to return a boolean to indicate whether the method finished successfully or not and a string with an error message in case of a problem.

I've implemented this in two ways.
The first consists in a class of response and all methods of all classes use this response class to communicate. Example:

```
public class ReturnValue {
    public bool Ok;
    public string Msg;
    public object SomeData;

    public ReturnValue() {
        this.Ok = true;
        this.Msg = null;
    }

    public ReturnValue(string Msg) {
        this.Ok = true;
        this.Msg = Msg;
    }

    public ReturnValue(object SomeData) {
        this.Ok = true;
        this.SomeData = SomeData;
    }

    public ReturnValue(bool Ok, string Msg) {
        this.Ok = Ok;
        this.Msg = Msg;
    }

    public ReturnValue(bool Ok, string Msg, object SomeData) {
        this.Ok = Ok;
        this.Msg = Msg;
        this.SomeData = SomeData;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public ReturnValue DoSomething() {
        if (true) {
            return new ReturnValue();
        } else {
            return new ReturnValue(false, "Something went wrong.");
        }
    }
}
```

The second way is to have a method that stores the message in case of error and to see the message simply call this method. Example:

```
public class Test {
    public string ReturnValue { get; protected set; }

    public bool DoSomething() {
        ReturnValue = "";

        if (true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ReturnValue = "Something went wrong.";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a right way to do this?

Comment: You could return an object array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on a return value to know if something succeeded, or what the error was if it didn't, C# generally relies on exceptions instead.  If your program works, don't throw an exception.  If it didn't work, throw an exception and include the error message in the exception thrown.

Comment: I generally agree, except in the case where you want to show a localized error message to the user. If you localize exception messages it's ok, if not, you have problems. It can also be a pain serializing exception messages for web calls.

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you need to handle that requirement you could always create your own type of exception that knows how to change the localization of it's error message.

Comment: So, all calls to that method I should wrap in a try catch block?

Comment: It would be valid also change the boolean return to void?

Comment: @VictorSantos Yes, if you throw an exception then you won't need to return the success status.

Comment: @VictorSantos That depends; not all callers may be in a position to handle the exception right away.  If they are, they should catch the exception, if they won't know what to do with it once they catch it then they should let the exception bubble up to their caller, and so on, until you get to the point where someone knows what to do with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use the `ref` keyword.

```
public bool DoSomething(ref string returnValue) {
    returnValue = "something";
    return true;
} 


string returnValue = "";
DoSomething(ref returnValue);
// returnValue now has new value.
```

Comment: In this context it should be `out` not `ref`, since the method doesn't need to read the value.  Additionally throwing an exception would be better than either option.

Comment: @Servy Good point, it should be `out` for this situation, and yes, throwing an exception is most likely a better solution.